# Why Label is hidden when I check the checkbox in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show title but when i checked the checkbox the label is hide.

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in user.widgets track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="user.widgets[$index]">
      <label> {{user.widgets[$index].title}}</label>
      <br>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you check your checkbox, you overrides `user.widgets[$index]` with true. So you can not access `user.widgets[$index].title`.

You can use widget instead of user.widgets[$index]. It's the current object.

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in user.widgets track by $index">
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="widget.isChecked">
     <label>{{widget.title}}</label>
     <br>
</div>
```